# What are the design patterns for Rest API automation using java

Tags: automation, rest-assured

I am a new to REST API automation project, as part of that I have learned using jayway rest assured instead of jersy client. Now, the problem is I am able to use protocol methods and getting response to parse and checking required data is not.

Now,

> I want to explore more to implement project setup like a pro, by using structured java classes or by using any class designs.
>
> I want to use this project for load testing
> I want to learn parameterization, i.e., First request's response may be input to 4th request (ex: login token id used for subsequent requests)
> I also want to know how to feed data as input from external files

Note: I have searched for sample projects on other channels but they are not as per my requirement and I spent time to understand those project but going over my head, couldn't able to understand their style of implementation  :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several things that you need to learn/understand:

1. It is not about design patterns, them you should learn in any case to consider yourself as a good developer or software engineer in test
2. REST Assured - is indeed for API testing, yes, but not the best
   choice, or even, is the last choice for load/performance testing
3. Haveing request based dependencies, more sound like component testing or end-to-end testing which is usually also the last choice
   and have to be as minimum as possible
4. Load/performance tools that you can choose and learn by your preferences are (not a full list, but ones that I used to use)

   - [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/)
   - [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
   - [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)